# PhpStorm open file and replace the previous

Tags: ide, phpstorm

I have an issue with my PhpStorm 2019.2.5, when I open a file and I want an another file, the IDE replace the previous file.

I can't have more one file open :(

Can you help me ?

Comment: Are you in Distraction Free mode or alike (check `Main Menu | View | Appearance`). Other than that -- check `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | General | Editor Tabs | Tab Limit` value

Comment: No, i'm not in Distraction Free mode, when I see my tab limit, it display : 50 (Recent files limit). I'm on  Windows 10 :)

Comment: 1) Disable all custom (not bundled by default) plugins, restart IDE and try again. Maybe it's one of the plugins. 2) Would be great if you can show some screenshots (or much better screencast) of how your IDE window looks like (whole window, not just part of it).

Comment: I disable all my plugins but Phpstorm always open one file and replace if I click an another code source page :( Here tou can find the picture : https://i.ibb.co/7bz3TSq/phpstorm.png

Comment: I do not see any editor tabs there .. which suggests that you may have disabled them (on purpose or accidentally). If you set to not to show them, then IDE will work as if only 1 tab is opened -- that's current behaviour (that changed from prev major version). Go to `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | General | Editor Tabs` and set `Tab Placement` to Top.

Comment: Thank you very much @LazyOne, that config solve my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to your screenshot (https://i.ibb.co/7bz3TSq/phpstorm.png) I do not see any editor tabs there which suggests that you may have disabled them (on purpose or accidentally). If you set to not to show editor tabs then IDE will work as if only 1 tab is opened -- that's the current behaviour.

To resolve it: go to `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | General | Editor Tabs` and set `Tab Placement` option to be `Top`.